# cursore within prusider mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

i'm trying to slice a long double Column by Varied size , and insert it with cursor to new table that has this size of columns amount.
the trouble is the cursor isn't responding?
I tried to activate the cursor (Externally) manually And managed to.
So I have the impression cursor does not work within procedure?!
**Here's the code:
The outer procedure:**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `slice_arrays`(IN `size` INT)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE h INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE q_creat text DEFAULT "";
DECLARE cell text DEFAULT "cell";
DECLARE cell_type text DEFAULT "double";
DECLARE new_table_name text DEFAULT "";

set new_table_name=CONCAT("table_1440_slice_by_",size);
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM eurusd_1440_minute_timeframe_chart_bars INTO n;
SET @q_creat =CONCAT("CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS ",new_table_name," (");



WHILE h < size DO
SET @q_creat =   CONCAT(@q_creat,cell,h," ",cell_type);

set @h_pluse_1=h+1;
if  @h_pluse_1 = size THEN 
SET @q_creat= CONCAT(@q_creat,")");
else 
SET @q_creat= CONCAT(@q_creat,",");
end if;

set h=h+1;
END WHILE;

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @q_creat;




EXECUTE stmt1;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;



TRUNCATE TABLE new_table_name;
set h=0;





set @temp_cuonter=size;

WHILE @temp_cuonter <= n DO



drop table IF EXISTS temp_table;


create table temp_table as (SELECT * FROM table_1440_test3  LIMIT h , size);



CALL insert_into_selected_table_from_temp_table(new_table_name);

 set h=h+1;
 set @temp_cuonter =@temp_cuonter+1;


TRUNCATE TABLE tamp_table;

end while;



End
```

**The nested procedure:**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_into_selected_table_from_temp_table`(IN `table_name` TEXT)
    DETERMINISTIC
begin
set @insert_q= CONCAT("INSERT INTO ",table_name," VALUES("); 






set @insert_q= CONCAT(@insert_q,get_temp_table(),")"); 

PREPARE stmt2 FROM @insert_q;
EXECUTE stmt2;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;
 end
```

**thanks!**

Comment: When I canceled TRUNCATE TABLE new_table_name;

Comment: When I canceled the TRUNCATE TABLE new_table_name; and TRUNCATE TABLE tamp_table; orders the code start working. Is there a reason Why the emptying table Causes disable add more rows ???